# if a cv::Mat is constructed with user-allocated data, does it then take care of its deletion?

Tags: c++, opencv, allocation

If I allocate an OpenCV Matrix with data from an array, e.g.

```
float* pfData = new float[ 120 * 310 ];    
cv::Mat M( 120, 310, CV_32F, pfData);
```

Then, the data is NOT copied, but simply used by cv::Mat.

But:

Does the cv::Mat as well take care of fee-ing the allocated data? Or does this remain my job?

Best,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it myself...

It says here

http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html

"The external data is not automatically deallocated, so you should take care of it."

Best,
Ben

Comment: Correct. You can accept your own answer, it will help others as feedback.